# A question regarding reactive power

Tags: power, power-electronics, generator, power-engineering, electric-machine

Why does the production of reactive power not require extra fuel unlike active/real power?

Comment: Note that power can't be converted into KE, because watts are not joules.   Generators send out electric energy.  This energy might be dumped into a capacitor-load, then the capacitor dumps it back into the generator again, repeating twice per cycle.

Comment: I think OP is asking if the generator will motor when real power flows form load to source.

Comment: Hello Jirhs. I'm a bit confused by what you're asking. Are you asking if the 2nd quarter of the sine wave that represents AC-generated electricity represents a negative flow of energy? That's not what's happening. Electrons are flowing into the reactive load in both quarters *so long as the generator is being driven.* If what you're asking is, "if I turn the generator through the first quarter, then disengage the generator for the period of the second quarter, will the generator become a motor?" the answer is, in an ideal world, yes. Which Q are you asking?

Comment: JBH, but doesn't power flow from load to source, in the 2nd quarter when the voltage goes down. And yes my question is the second one, but why does the generator have to be disengaged

Comment: The transportation of reactive power **does** require the burning of fuel.

Comment: Why does the production of it require no additional fuel?

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Generating reactive power needs fuel. Theoretically it's an one time investment to produce the extra energy contained in the fluctuating field, but the extra current in circuits cause losses, so also some continuous extra demand of fuel exists.

Comment: So fuel is needed once for setting up the feilds, after that it's only for i^2 r losses

Comment: Yes, except we do not know what the generator actually does.  In theory it can dissipate everything which returns from the load. In that case there's continuous demand of fuel also for the reactive power. I have kept in my hands radio transmitters which dissipate all the power reflected from the mismatched antenna.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, reactive power generation requires fuel!

Let's not mix the concepts of inrush with reactivity. Inrush in a generator (or transformer - but I'll talk only of a generator) is overwhelmingly inductive and declines to a steady state value to maintain the magnetic fields in the generator's rotor coils, but does not disappear. The work done by the rotor coils in maintaining the magnetic field allows for the transfer of the mechanical energy from the rotor to the electrical energy in the stator.

If you look only at the voltage and current wave forms, the reverse flow of power when voltage and current are opposite polarities in their sine waves serves to slow down the rotor, so the generator has to have extra fuel burned to maintain the rotor speed. The more the waves are out of phase, the more the "braking" effect on the rotor. Note that the difference between a motor and a generator is which side has more power input. Traction motors (e.g., subways and EV's) serve as "regenerative brakes", meaning the motor converts to a generator, even though it's the same physical device.

Additionally, the reactive loads fed by the generator need continual energy supply to maintain their magnetic fields so they can do their work in transforming the electrical energy into whatever form the appliance or machine provides, and that supply must come from the source if it does not come from a nearby capacitor bank (think "power factor correction").

Any time something "works", that work uses energy that must be supplied from somewhere. The work of a generator or machine is the conversion of energy from one form to another. It's not free work.

Terminology of "imaginary" power can be misleading. It is *mathematically* imaginary (square root of -1), not conceptually imaginary.

Early metering technology could only measure either "real" (kW) or "imaginary" (kVAr) components, and to get the full (or "Apparent") power (kVA) would require two meters and two times the cost. For residential and small-commercial loads the extra cost was not justified, so folks got used to only looking at the "real" or resistive component of power/energy. Electronic meters now measure both components, but DOUGs (Dumb Old Utility Guys, like me) are used to things changing only once every century or so, so we still largely base residential and small commercial rates and measurements on the real component only.